# Is a compact, bounded, closed subset of a normed vector space necessarily of finite dimension?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let be X a Normed Vector Space, my question is:
if a set A contained in X is compact, bounded, closed, is it finite dimension?

I was looking for a characterization of the dimension of an nvs using Heine Borel theorem. suppose i have a Compact operator between an Hilbert space and itself, i want to proof that the autospace generated by the eigenvectors (i'll call it A_L) is finite dimensional. I know from the previous theorems and lemmas that A_L is closed, now my question is: if i show that the orthonormal base of A_L is bounded, precompact therefore compact, is it finite dimension?

Comment: Are you asking if $A$ is finite dimensional? How do you define its dimension?

Comment: First of all, compact in a metric space implies closed and bounded. Secondly: there is no reason to be finite dimensional.

Comment: suppose that A is an NVS, i was looking for a characterization of the dimension of an nvs using Heine Borel. suppose i have a Compact operator between an Hilbert space and itself, i want to proof that the autospace generated by the eigenvectors (i'll call it A_L) is finite dimensional. I know from the previous theorems and lemmas that A_L is closed, now my question is: if i show that A_L is bounded, precompact therefore compact, is it finite dimension?

Comment: How can an autospace be bounded? Any non-zero subspace cannot be bounded.

Comment: i can apply the same reasoning at the complete orthonormal base that generate A_L

Answer (score 5):

Consider the following example: $X=\ell^2=\{(x_n):\sum|x_n|^2<\infty\}$ and
$$
A=\{(x_n)\in\ell^2:|x_n|\le1/n\}=[-1,1]\times\Bigl[-\frac12,\frac12\Bigr]\times\dots\times\Bigl[-\frac1n,\frac1n\Bigr]\times\dotsm
$$